# ReferenceError: nv is not defined in ionic2

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am trying to implement nvd3 charts in ionic2 by importing them from the `node_modules` instead of the online resources.

It works when I import the scripts from an online resource (`index.html`)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.8.4/nv.d3.min.css"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.8.4/nv.d3.min.js"></script>
```

But when I try to import them from the `node_modules` it fails.

```
<link href="../node_modules/nvd3/build/nv.d3.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="../node_modules/d3/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="../node_modules/nvd3/build/nv.d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: **Note for anyone trying to solve this from the angular2 tag**: `ionic2` doesn't use `systemjs.config`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Hey I solved by adding the three files under assets/libs folder in the src folder in the project.    
<link href="assets/libs/nv.d3.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="assets/libs/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="assets/libs/nv.d3.min.js" ></script>
```